# Cannot Connect to Wireless Wifi version 17.04 (no available networks shown)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, broadcom

This may seem like a duplicate question, but I have spent hours searching through the Ubuntu and StackExchange forums looking for an answer and cannot find anything that works.  Yesterday, I downloaded Ubuntu 17.04.  The first thing I did was to attempt to connect the OS to the internet.  I went to Network settings, and discovered that I had two options: Wired or Network Proxy (I can also add a VPN).  There was nothing in the menu bar other than the 'Help' option; there also weren't any other extended options besides those under Wired or Network Proxy (which is why the Ubuntu wireless troubleshoot page isn't helping).

I have checked, and I do have the following Network controller:
Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

I looked under Additional Drivers and found that it says that the OS is running the driver; specifically "Using Broadcom 802.11 Linus STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (open source)".  However, no matter what I do, I cannot see or find the wireless network I need to connect to.

This computer is a Dell, only about 2 years old, and the original OS is Windows 10.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl` ? Required key not available?? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks!  The output was "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available"